# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json for DTO with @xmlrootelement

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to understand in what scenarios (if possible) does one get this type of exception:

> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json for DTO
>   with @xmlrootelement

**Yes,** my maven dependencies are correct and I even have two similar DTOs that work just fine letting `Jersey` handle the content negotiation/marshalling...

For some reason, I get the previous mentioned exception with the following:

*Resource method:*

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@WebinarSecurityFilter
public Response getXYZ( @QueryParam("startDate") LocalDate start, 
                                    @QueryParam("endDate") LocalDate end, 
                                    @QueryParam("excludesubaccounts") String excludeSubAcc){

    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate startDate = start == null ? now.minusDays(30) : start;
    LocalDate endDate = end == null ? now : end;
    boolean excludeSubAccounts = excludeSubAcc != null  && "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(excludeSubAcc);


    List<ABC> resultQuery = abcService.getABCs(clientId, startDate, endDate, excludeSubAccounts);

    CLA cla= new CLA();

    cla.setId(clientId);
    cla.setA(resultQuery);
    cla.setB(resultQuery.size());

    return Response.ok(cla).build();
}
```

*DTO/DTOContainer:*

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CLA{

    private long id;
    private long a;
    private long b;

    @XmlElement(name = "abc")
    private List<ABC> ABCs;
//setters & getters
}
```

*DTO:*

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class ABC{

// a lot of fields
//setters & getters
}
```

I've used this same exact scenario with other DTOs, so why is **this** one not working ?

My question is, are there specific scenarios where Jersey/Jackson aren't able to to this task and one has to do it manually or am I missing something and just have blindness ?

Here's the exception:

> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,
>   type=class com.CLA, genericType=class com.CLA

Its not that it sometimes works, and sometimes it doesn't, it just **doesn't** work for **this** resource method even though I have two other resource methods that do the same exact thing but with different DTOs

Comment: In a scenario like this where it "sometimes works and sometimes doesn't", I highly suggest you post _real_ code. And please also post your dependencies. I don't even have to test, and I can already tell that what you posted (with the dependencies I "imagine in my head") should would work if I tested it. Please post enough _real_ information, that you have tested to actually fail. And post the entire stack trace.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this same scenario is used with two different DTOs and they work just fine. My question is very clear.

Comment: I dont think adding a couple of fields to the DTO will give you any info at all and the only place where i gave all the code was in the resource method.

Comment: I never said it "sometimes works and sometimes doesn't", but let me rephrase my question, try to make it clearer.

Comment: Well I can tell you without even testing that If you I used the code from your post, with jersey-media-json-jackson, that it would work (and I would not get the error you are mentioning). So I'm saying that it's something that is probably not obvious that is the problem. Something that is _not_ included in your post. What I would suggest is to start a new project with the minimal dependencies. Add _just_ the classes (stripped down even) that are needed to reproduce the problem. And the update your post with all this information, from dependencies to classes, and how you make the request.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more specific situations when the error happen? Since I just see you declare `@Produces` annotations but there is no `@Consumes` annotations I think this error happen when you send a request? If this is the case, just add this either on your desire method or just put it above the class name:

```
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
```

But if this is not the case, maybe is because you need to specify that you want to send request and receive response in json, so add this in your request header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: That's the thing, this is the only place where it has happened. and it only has a `@Produces` because it's a GET

Comment: Oh and yes, the headers are set as you placed them

Comment: Try remove `@XmlRootElement` at ABC class